# PreScan error when using Matlab 2018a

Tags: matlab

PreScan is a vehicle simulation software I'm working with.
https://tass.plm.automation.siemens.com/prescan
It works fine when using Simulink in Matlab 2015b, however it shows error when using Matlab 20178a.

```
    Error using mex
C:\Users\watouser\AppData\Roaming\TNO\PreScan\8.2.0\sfunction_R2018a\sfun_Controller.c:44:0: warning: "MX_COMPAT_32" redefined
 #define MX_COMPAT_32
 ^
<command-line>:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
C:\Users\watouser\AppData\Roaming\TNO\PreScan\8.2.0\sfunction_R2018a\sfun_Controller.c: In function 'void mdlStart(SimStruct*)':
C:\Users\watouser\AppData\Roaming\TNO\PreScan\8.2.0\sfunction_R2018a\sfun_Controller.c:548:67: error: 'prescan_get_host_flags'
was not declared in this scope
       prescan_controller_setflags(&work1, prescan_get_host_flags(S));
                                                                   ^


Error in legacycode.LCT/compile

Error in legacycode.LCT.legacyCodeImpl

Error in legacy_code (line 101)
[varargout{1:nargout}] = legacycode.LCT.legacyCodeImpl(action, varargin{1:end});

Error in build_Controller

Error in build_rtw_blocks

Error in prepare_sfunctions

Error in SimCore_startup_common

Error in prescan_startup
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your Prescan version is simply not compatible with Matlab 2018a.
As of August 2018 Prescan only lists compatiblity with Matlab 2017b on their site:
https://tass.plm.automation.siemens.com/new-prescan